# Android - How to mask EditView with an overlay view

Tags: android, mobile, layout, user-interface, android-edittext

I'm trying to overlay EditText with another view. My Layout seems to work, however the EditText is still clickable. What am I missing?

***Here is my basic layout:***

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:inputType="text"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#00aa00"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
</LinearLayout>
```

***and here is the emulator view:***

[image]

**Update:**
I'm animating the LinearLayout to show or hide the EditText

Comment: It is unclear what you exactly want. You want to hide the `EditText` and not be able to click it? Then do not write the `EditText` code.

Comment: add  android:clickable="false", why do you need it?

Comment: I'm animating the LinearLayout to show or hide the text

Comment: @Shlomi Schwartz Try my answer, So that edittext cant consume click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put  `android:clickable="true"` in `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to be more clear in this question. I'm not sure exactly what the point of covering your 'EditText' altogether is. If you'd like to disable the 'EditText' you can use the '.setEnabled()' method and pass it 'false'.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#00aa00"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:inputType="text"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this puts the EditText on top of my LinearLayout